# Locale does not get change in titleWindow

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, locale

I have some labels in a title window in my application. When i change locale it gets changed but labels in the titleWindow do not change. When I check the locale chain using `resourceManager.localeChain` it returns the array of locales and newly selected locale is on the zero index of it. 
I am finding no way to fix this problem.

Comment: You should provide some sample code that may clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to override the *resourcesChanged* method from the TitleWindow?

```
override protected function resourcesChanged():void {
   super.resourcesChanged();
   //load the labels
   someComponent.label = resourceManager.getString('labels', 'THE_LABEL');
}
```

This method is called each time the ResourcesManager changes (dispatches a "change" event), including when the locale is updated.